# Determinant (Cauchy?)

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have to show that

${det}\left ( \begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_i^2 & \sum_{i=1}^{n}t_i\\ 
\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_i & n
\end{bmatrix} \right )>0$

**My solution so far**

$n \cdot (\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_i^2)-(\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_i)^2>0\Leftrightarrow$

$n \cdot (\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_i^2)>(\sum_{i=1}^{n}t_i)^2\Leftrightarrow \\$

$n(t_{1}^2+t_{2}^2+...+t_{n}^2)>(t_{1}+t_{2}+...+t_{n})^2$

All the $t$'s are not the same. But my conclusion seems wrong. Can I use Cauchy or any other method to make it obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint : $n=1+1+ \cdots +1$ and use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I have tried but can not seem to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

Sum of squares is non-negative. So$$\sum\left(t_i-\frac1n\sum t_i\right)^2\ge0$$

Open the outer sum,$$\begin{align*}\sum t_i^2+\frac1{n^2}\sum\left(\sum t_i\right)^2-\frac2n\sum\left(t_i\sum t_i\right)&\ge0\\\sum t_i^2+\frac1n\left(\sum t_i\right)^2-\frac2n\left(\sum t_i\right)^2&\ge0\\\sum t_i^2&\ge \frac{(\sum t_i)^2}n\end{align*}$$The equality occurs iff $t_i=\frac1n\sum t_i$ i.e. $t_i$ are constant.

Comment: I have not learned of a way of using the mean. Can this not be done in another way?

Comment: @mathstudent23 I have written $\bar t$ just as a shorthand concise notation to denote $\sum t_i$. I have not used any properties of mean and my calculations are purely algebraic.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding this approach might be a bit outside of my realm. Looking at how i did it; Could it be done in a similar but correct manner that shows the equality holds?

Comment: You have just simplified the determinant but not shown that it is positive. This is one of the ways to show it positive. I have removed all references to mean and variance now.

Answer (score 2):

Hint : $n=1+1+ \cdots +1$ and use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

The CS inequality states
\begin{eqnarray*}
(a_1^2+a_2^2+ \cdots +a_n^2)(b_1^2+b_2^2+ \cdots +b_n^2) \geq (a_1 b_1+a_2 b_2+ \cdots +a_n b_n)^2.
\end{eqnarray*}
For your question you need $a_i=1$  and $b_i=t_i$.

Comment: Okay so my solution is correct so far and then I show that the inequality holds because of this:

Comment: Yeah, sorry I should have said ... Your solution so far is fine, you just need to conclude that the final inequality is true by virtue of the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Let $e=(1,...,1)^T\in\mathbb{R}^n,t=(t_1,..,t_n)^T$ then we have $|e|^2=1^2+...+1^2=n$ hence by Cauchy Schwarz we have $$|<e,t>|^2=|t_1+...+t_n|^2\leq |t|^2|e|^2=(t_1^2+...t_n^2)n$$
Since $<e,t>=e_1t_1+...e_nt_n=t_1+...+t_n$.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding this approach might be a bit outside of my realm. Looking at how i did it; Could it be done in a similar but correct manner that shows the equality holds?

Comment: Cauchy Schwarz inequality tells you that the equality holds if and only if the two vectors are linearly dependent, i.e. if $t=\lambda e$ which just means that all the $t_i$ are the same. Since this is forbidden by your assumption you get the strict inequality. :)

Comment: This is just the same as your approach. I only simplified my notation($<-,->$ denotes the standard scalarproduct in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $|-|$ the induced euclidean norm)